# JS CoffeeScript - Same random number from method

Tags: javascript, object, random, coffeescript

I've created a class in coffeescript with a randomInt method that generates x and y instance variables. However when I create objects from this class the x and y values are the different but consistent for both.

Here is the code to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/paulmason411/BvPBG/

```
class Shape

  getRandomInt = (min, max) ->
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min

  y: getRandomInt(1,100)
  x: getRandomInt(1,100)

shape1 = new Shape
shape2 = new Shape

alert(shape1.x)
alert(shape2.x)

alert(shape1.y)
alert(shape2.y)​
```

I need each alerted value to be different.

I searched for a solution and in other programming languages they use srand() however js doesn't have this native function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create "instance variables" of `x` and `y` (the `@` makes them such vars):

```
class Shape

  constructor: ->
    @x = Shape::getRandomInt(1,100)
    @y = Shape::getRandomInt(1,100)

  getRandomInt: (min, max) ->
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min


shape1 = new Shape
shape2 = new Shape

console.log(shape1.x)
console.log(shape2.x)
console.log(shape1.y)
console.log(shape2.y)
```

which printed:

```
48
13
9
86
```

Note that the `getRandomInt` function is added to `Shape.prototype`, and `Shape::getRandomInt(1,100)` is identical to `Shape.prototype.getRandomInt(1,100)`.